# Erro ao tentar Editar PK e UK no ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

Gostaria de saber como manipular as Unique Keys e Primary Keys com Entity Framework. Sempre que eu tento editar um atributo e passo o mesmo valor que ele possuía antes, me retorna um erro:

"The instance of entity type 'Unidade' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdUnidade'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

Se eu tentar não passar nada, o valor fica em branco, o que tambem está incorreto. Como eu deveria fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas eu to tentando atualizar o mesmo registro com o mesmo valor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está ocorrendo pois você está tentando dar update criando um novo registro, com a `PK` de uma já existente.

Ex, aqui você está criando uma nova `UnidadeDto`

> Domain.DTO.Unidade `unidadeDTO` = new Domain.DTO.Unidade();

e logo após está passando para dar o `UPDATE`, em um novo registro:

> _unidadeRepository.Update(`unidadeDTO`);

Sendo que a forma correta para atualizar a sua `unidadeDTO`, deveria ser primeiramente trazer o dado já existente do banco de dados +- da seguinte forma:

```
var unidadeDTO = _unidadeRepository.GetUnidadeById(unidadeDto.IdUnidade);

unidadeDTO.NomeUnidade = collection["nomeUnidade"];
unidadeDTO.EnderecoUnidade = enderecoDTO;
unidadeDTO.ImagemUnidade = "/img/Recebido/Perfil/Unidade/" + nomeArquivo;
```

e agora sim passar para o `UPDATE`:

> _unidadeRepository.Update(`unidadeDTO`);